# IFNULL and COALESCE don't seem to work

Tags: sqlite

I have the following table:

```
SELECT * FROM calls LIMIT 10;
time               |number     |duration|calltype
2011-02-21 19:06:19|11243243569|    NULL|missed
2010-07-12 17:47:14|11234123445|    NULL|missed
2010-07-01 20:55:14|11234123459|      52|placed
2010-07-24 22:43:53|12342345662|     363|received
2010-07-22 01:05:25|11234123412|    NULL|missed
2010-09-16 00:09:03|14321234231|    NULL|missed
2010-10-08 16:31:13|14234234253|    NULL|missed
2010-10-05 17:34:28|15534535234|    NULL|missed
2010-10-22 04:27:15|16127085031|    NULL|missed
2010-10-22 23:46:55|12182308974|    NULL|missed
```

I would like that durations of `NULL` be replaced by `0`, but `IFNULL` does not seem to work.

```
SELECT time,number,IFNULL(duration,0),calltype FROM calls LIMIT 10;
time               |     number|IFNULL(duration,0)|calltype
2011-02-21 19:06:19|11243243569|              NULL|missed
2010-07-12 17:47:14|11234123445|              NULL|missed
2010-07-01 20:55:14|11234123459|                52|placed
2010-07-24 22:43:53|12342345662|               363|received
2010-07-22 01:05:25|11234123412|              NULL|missed
2010-09-16 00:09:03|14321234231|              NULL|missed
2010-10-08 16:31:13|14234234253|              NULL|missed
2010-10-05 17:34:28|15534535234|              NULL|missed
2010-10-22 04:27:15|16127085031|              NULL|missed
2010-10-22 23:46:55|12182308974|              NULL|missed
```

Indeed, this problem arose while trying to use the `COALESCE()` `MAX()` aggregate operators and discovering that they also returned NULLs.

What might be going on here? How can I have aggregates ignore NULLs and `IFNULL` work?

**Update**

Using the `typeof` command on the columns results in this:

```
SELECT duration,typeof(duration) as typ FROM calls LIMIT 10;
duration|typ
    NULL|text
    NULL|text
      52|integer
     363|integer
    NULL|text
    NULL|text
    NULL|text
    NULL|text
    NULL|text
    NULL|text
```

Comment: I am using SQLite `3.8.2 2013-12-06 14:53:30 27392118af4c38c5203a04b8013e1afdb1cebd0d`

Comment: Upgrading to SQLite `3.8.7.2 2014-11-18 20:57:56 2ab564bf9655b7c7b97ab85cafc8a48329b27f93` did not change anything.

Comment: What is the output of `SELECT DISTINCT typeof(duration) FROM calls`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ifnull` function works only for values of type NULL, not for the text `'NULL'`.

To map the string `'NULL'` to something else, you can use a [CASE expression](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#case):

```
SELECT time,
       number,
       CASE duration WHEN 'NULL' THEN 0 ELSE duration END AS duration,
       calltype
FROM calls
```

It would be a better idea to use *real* NULL values.

Comment: And I'm using them now! The database was created partly via code reused from someone else's Python project, and that was printing the `"NULL"` string. Switching that to `None` in Python results in the `sqlite3` library printing _real_ `NULL` values.